# invalid ARN error on terraform when creating eks cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

```
**resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_role" {
  name = "eks_role"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = "aws_iam_role.eks_role.name"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSServicePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  role       = "aws_iam_role.eks_role.name"
}
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "t3_eks" {
  name     = "t3_eks"
  role_arn = "aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn"
  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = var.sg
    subnet_ids = var.subnets
    endpoint_private_access = false
    endpoint_public_access = true
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSServicePolicy,
  ]
}**
```

**Error message**
Error: "role_arn" (aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix

on EKS\main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "t3_eks":
30: resource "aws_eks_cluster" "t3_eks" {

Please could someone guide as to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Quotes are important with terraform. In 0.12 the quoted string "aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn" is just a string. In order for it to be interpolated as an actual variable, you need to remove the quotes:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "t3_eks" {
  name     = "t3_eks"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn
```

It is also possible to interpolate a variable inside of a string, which is required for terraform 0.11 or older:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "t3_eks" {
  name     = "t3_eks"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.eks_role.arn}"
```